# Password:hint showing as an regular text

Tags: android

Just noticed that android:password has been deprecated, and we should be using android:inputType. I did same and set hint text, but instead to show *** it is showing regular text

**Edit:**

```
android:hint="@string/papssword_hint"
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

in response it showing papssword_hint instead to convert it into ******* .

Anyone have suggestion if I am missing anything.

Comment: Did you mean that imputed text are showing when you set inputType is set to password and hint is being used?

Comment: if you are using this: android:inputType="textPassword" and having the problem, then, can you post your code?

Comment: I have updated question, please check.

Comment: it will show * or . when you type text there...

Answer (score 1):

A password hint is shown as regular text. It would be "useless" if the hint would be shown as dots instead of text.

Think of scenario where users have multiple passwords and you suggest which one to use in the hint, if it would be shown as * it would be unreadable and unhelpful.

**EDIT:** If you'd like to show dots, set the following as hint:

> android:hint="........"

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml, remove inputType:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

And in your java code:

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

You can keep the hint in .xml as it is.

Comment: Thanks but this is not making any change for me at least...still password hint showing as an text instead of ******.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private TextView txtPhoneNumber;
txtPhoneNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCoursemetsPhoneNumbe
txtPhoneNumber.setHint("Phone number");
```